# Smarty dynamic variable issue

Tags: php, mysql, smarty, smarty3

Unfortunately, in my current workplace, I have to use Smarty on a project they had before i was employed.

Anyway, I am trying to call in a Dynamic html title for each category in the app.

So for example, the title used to be `pageTitle="{$category}` in `{$areaname}`".

However I now want it to be: `pageTitle="{html_title}"`. Within `html_title` (from db), is a string, for example: "`Monkeys in the {areaname}`"  Where `{areaname}` could be `"jungle`".

When I output the result, I get:

`"Monkeys in {areaname}"`.

So to cut a long story short, its not recognizing the variable. It is treating it as a string. I have googled my head off and can't find an answer. I hate smarty!
Please help!

Comment: Monkeys in the {$areaname} will not work?

Comment: I can't work out why? In Smarty can you not have a variable within a variable?

Comment: How do you set "{html_title}" ? In this (wrong) way ?  `$smarty->assign("html_title","Monkeys in {areaname}")` ?

Comment: It is set using a plugin: {getServiceCategoryTitle categoryID=$id assign="html_title"}

Comment: And the value from the database is "Monkey in the {$areaName}".  {$areaName} is already assigned elsewhere on the page. But instead of displaying the value of {$areaName} it is actually displaying {$areaName}

Comment: "Monkey in the {$areaName}" is only a string and Smarty works right. It doesn't process the output of functions or plugins. I suppose that you should process this string during "getServiceCategoryTitle" execution, before return the value.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just do something like

```
$html_title = preg_replace("/{areaname}/", "jungle", $html_title);
```

after fetching the title from the database?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want to go down this road but oh well. I hate Smarty!!